# Ethereum Dapp Account Login Protocol with Metamask

Tags: dapp-development, metamask, accounts, cryptography, public-key

I'm building an Ethereum dapp for users to use with Metamask. We're going to have an account management system and I was trying to follow this post on how to achieve a "password-less" account system using Metamask: https://hackernoon.com/never-use-passwords-again-with-ethereum-and-metamask-b61c7e409f0d.

However, there is a problem with the suggested protocol as the signed data never changes, so an attacker could just intercept the signed message and could authenticate as that user.

I was trying to find a previously devised public-key algorithm on Wikipedia, but most protocol involve a trust authority -- I don't know if that's necessary here.

What's a simple, but secure or established protocol for authenticating a user in this way? I was considering a nonce system + signing with eth wallet private key.

Comment: From that post: "This data is arbitrary and can be any random string that the website’s API serves up." I think this is probably what you mean by a "nonce system." I think the threat to be concerned with is a man-in-the-middle attack as described here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1839.

Comment: Implementation tutorial `One-click Login with Blockchain: A MetaMask Tutorial` https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial